# QMake/Make subproject rebuild on change

Tags: makefile, qmake

I am currently trying to integrate a thirdparty library into my qmake build process. I added the thirdparty library repo as a submodule. The structure of this repository is:

```
├── ComBase
│   │   main.c
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── libCom.a
│   │   └── libCom.so
│   ├── Makefile
├── _Linux
└── Makefile
```

There are multiple subdirectories like ComBase all creating a library of their own.
The toplevel Makefile looks like this:

```
MKFILE_PATH := $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
MKFILE_DIR := $(dir $(MKFILE_PATH))

SUBPROJECTS = $(MKFILE_DIR)/ComBase \
          $(MKFILE_DIR)/OtherLib

TARGET_DIR=$(MKFILE_DIR)/_Linux

#Build rules begin.
all: $(SUBPROJECTS)

$(SUBPROJECTS): 
    $(MAKE) -C $@ -f Makefile
    cp $@/lib/* $(TARGET_DIR)

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET_DIR)/*
    $(foreach subproj,$(SUBPROJECTS), $(MAKE) -C $(subproj) -f Makefile clean;)

.PHONY: clean all
```

And my main qt qmake file looks like this:

```
comlib.target = comlib
comlib.commands = make -f $${OUT_PWD}/../../thirdparty/comlib/Makefile
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += comlib
LIBS += -L$${OUT_PWD}/../../thirdparty/comlib/_Linux -lCom 
PRE_TARGETDEPS += $${OUT_PWD}/../../thirdparty/comlib/_Linux/libCom.so
```

What I want to achieve is if anything changes say in the `main.c` file of the ComBase libary the qmake process notices it and rebuilds the libary before building/linking the actual qt project to it. The first problem I noticed that when I modify the `main.c` and call the Makefile in the thirdparty submodule (thirdparty/comlib/Makefile) directly it does not trigger rebuild of the ComBase lib(thirdparty/comlib/ComBase/Makefile).

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this was adding $(SUBPROJECTS) as a .PHONY target. Also adjustment of this line:

```
PRE_TARGETDEPS += comlib
```